# highlight text color in given string in php

Tags: php

I have a string like `p12200` in my query result set. Users search `p-122-0` or `p122-0` embedding dashes any where in searched text, but i want to highlight the `p1220` text at our front-end. I am using the replace keyword in database, and it return the correct result set but I am color highlighting the result set.

My function to color highlight is:

```
function strreplace($searchstring, $result) {

 if(stripos($searchstring,'-')===false) return str_ireplace($searchstring, "<span class='highlightcolor'>".$searchstring."</span>", $result);
 else {

 if(stripos($result,'-')===false) return str_ireplace(str_ireplace('-','',$searchstring), "<span class='highlightcolor'>".str_ireplace('-','',$searchstring)."</span>", $result);
 elseif(stripos($result,'-')!==false)  return str_ireplace(str_ireplace('-','',$searchstring), "<span class='highlightcolor'>".$searchstring."</span>", $result);

 }

}
```

Please suggest if i made any mistake with my code.

Comment: why don't you jquery highlight

Comment: no this is not working for me.
I have a result set "P1220-0004-BA:P1220 512uDOCXpe256MBRFID" and i searched the P1220-0. it replaces the - in result set, but i want to highlight the result with dashes.

Comment: @user2223377 please see edit below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function highlight(str, className) {

      jQuery( "#resultcontainer td" ).each(function() {

  var val = jQuery(this).text();//get the string value
  var match='';

  if(val.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase())!==-1)
    {   
      match = val.substr(val.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()),str.length);

    }
    else if(val.replace(/\-/g,'').toLowerCase().indexOf(str.replace(/\-/g,'').toLowerCase())!==-1)
    { 
        match = getMatch (val,str.replace(/\-/g,''),'');
    }
    if(match!=''){
    var regex = new RegExp("("+match+")", "gi");
    var n = val.replace(regex,"<span class='"+className+"'>"+match+"</span>");     //replace the match with highlight color
    jQuery(this).html(n);
    }

 });
```

}

```
function getMatch(string,searchString,match)
 {

var i = searchString.length;
var m = string.length;
var j = 0;
    var stringarray = string.split("");
var searcharray = searchString.split("");

 for(var k=0;k<i;k++){

    if(j>=m) break;

     for(;j<m;j++){

        if(k>=i) return match;

     if(searcharray[k] == stringarray[j]) {
        if(match=='-' || match=='') {var l = j;} // sotre the first match index value
        match = match+stringarray[j];
        k++;

      }
      else if(stringarray[j]=='-'){
      match = match+stringarray[j];
      }
      else {
       if(match!='' && match!=='-') 
           j = l;
       match = '';
       k = 0;
      }

     }

 }

  return match;

}

  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        highlight("p-1-22-0", "highlightcolor");
   });
```